# Python list if else save

Tags: python, list

If I have this list for example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to replace for example `x < 3 x = 'L'` to be:   `list = [L, L, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

```
if x < 3:
    list = [L, L, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
elif x > 2 x = 'S1':
    list = [L, L, S1, S1, S1, 6, 7]
elif x > 5 x = 'L':
    list = [L, L, S1, S1, S1, 'L', 'L']
```

The point is to save my list after every if or elif.

Comment: So you want to replace any number with`'S1'` if it is greater than two and not greater than 5; otherwise with `'L'`. Is that right?

Comment: Could you write it better please? What is x what do you mean by save my list?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to replace any number with`'S1'` if it is greater than two and not greater than 5; otherwise with `'L'`.

If I understand your question right, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
lst = ['S1' if 2 < x <= 5 else 'L' for x in lst]
```

Outcome:

```
['L', 'L', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'L', 'L']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` arrays, create the array with the `ints`, a second one full of empty string because it avoid multi-type in one array which will make the after-first-one condition fail

```
# import numpy as np
vals   = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
result = np.array(["" for _ in range(len(vals))])

result[vals < 3] = 'L'
result[vals > 2] = 'S1'
result[vals > 5] = 'L'
print(result) # ['L' 'L' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'L' 'L']
```

Answer (score 0):

One Liner Solution,Use map function

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(list(map(lambda x : "L" if x < 3 else x,_list)))
#['L', 'L', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```